# recommended librairies for a dynamic data-driven website

Tags: javascript, user-interface, tree, real-time

First I know this might be received as an opinion-based question. If it is the case, could you advise some other appropriate places to get some feedback.

I want to make a web app that renders graphically tree data structure that needs to be updated on the browser as the data changes in real time on the server, and as we navigate through the data on the client-side (like if we were moving through a 2D map in a game, getting data as we progress and as it changes)..

I can do MongoDB, nodejs, and react at the moment. I'm planning to have a deeper look graphQL based on a guess that it might be helpful. Other than that I don't have too many ideas regarding open connections (is there anything other than socket.io that I should look into?)

About the GUI, I did a bit of canvas, a while ago, but I really don't know in which directions to look to see what exists today, and even if it is worth getting refreshed in python for example..

Any feedbacks appreciated before the question is deleted..

Comment: you can use firebase. it is a realtime no-sql database. with firebase, backendside is not needed, you only need to focus on your frontend. it is simple to use and supports social authentication, cloud functions, and file storage

Comment: thanks angel, yeah I'm going to look at D3js and firebase for a start ^^thanks